# Any direct approach to add all elements in a single shot to the collection objects?

Tags: collections, excel, vbscript, vba

I know the `Add method` to add elements to the `dictionary` objects and `ArrayList` objects.So Is there any way to add elements to such collections in a single shot using VBScript,not one by one.

Thanks,

Comment: Only if you had `ToDictionary()` built in method... perhaps converting Array to `Dictionary/Collection`...

Comment: @bonCodigo Does `ToDictionary()` present in VBScript?

Comment: Humm,That means no way to have it :-)

Comment: Rolling your own would be pretty trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array from a string with split, but it is quite limited:

```
Split("a,b,c,d",",")
```

Similarly, Array

```
Array("a","b","c")
```

Finally, you can read a textfile into a recordset, but that may be overkill, unless you have a large number of values.